# Emails on other server, dns & mx

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I must host emails on other server, my way was:

1. Edit DNS to my server
2. MX Record edit in the zone file (editing with a GUI)

If I change for example SOA serial, retry, refresh then are my changes not visible, also I can't see option where to edit "Reverse MX A records (PTR)", my question is, 
if is only MX Record edited, it's ok to get emails working from other server? On my server I need only www, means website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to ask your ISP to setup the PTR for you.

You can have something like mail.example.com for your mail server and have that as the PTR. It is important because many mail servers will otherwise flat out refuse your emails (like mine for example.)

Otherwise you can test that the mail.example.com is valid by pinging it to make sure that the DNS works as expected. If you are under Linux, you can use dig (with my domain):

```
dig -t MX m2osw.com
```

That will show you something like this:

```
m2osw.com.      86400   IN  MX  10 mail.m2osw.com.
```

Which looks like it is working.

To see the IP address and make sure that it points to the correct server:

```
dig mail.m2osw.com
```

Note that when you change an IP in a DNS it can take "a while" before it fully updates because other servers will have the old IP cached. Servers you have no direct control over.

Comment: The emails are on hotmail, and i edited MX record to hotmail, it's the ip also to set on mail.mydomain.com?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are asking then. If you receive your emails on hotmail, then you certainly have no control. If you want to forward your hotmail emails to another server, then you have to change the settings on hotmail to have them forwarded automatically.